# Matrix Translation in GLSL is infinitely stretched

Tags: matrix, opengl-es, glsl, webgl, coordinate-transformation

I work with webgl and modify the shaders (vs.glsls and fs.glsl) to understand the GLSL and graphic programming. I have a model that I want to scale, rotate and translate. Scaling and rotating works fine but when I multiply the translation matrix, the result is weird. I know this is a very basic question, but I am missing something and I need to find it out.
my model is infinitely stretchered through the y axis.

The white area is supposed to be the eye of the model:

[image: The white area is supposed to be the eye of the model]

this is my vertex shader code:

```
mat4 rX = mat4 (
 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
 );

mat4 rZ = mat4 (
 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
 );

mat4 eyeScale = mat4 (
 .50,0.0,0.0,0.0,
 0.0,.50,0.0,0.0,
 0.0,0.0,.50,0.0,
 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
 );
mat4 eyeTrans = mat4(
1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
0.0,1.0,0.0,4.0,
0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,
0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
);
 mat4 iR = eyeTrans*rZ*rX*eyeScale;
 gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix  *iR* vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried it again and same result. instead of translating the model, it stretches the model. I will add a picture to the question so you can see the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You swapped rows and columns, when you set up the translation matrix

Change it to:

```
mat4 eyeTrans = mat4(
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0
);
```

A 4*4 matrix looks like this:

```
  c0  c1  c2  c3            c0  c1  c2  c3
[ Xx  Yx  Zx  Tx ]        [  0   4   8  12 ]     
[ Xy  Yy  Zy  Ty ]        [  1   5   9  13 ]     
[ Xz  Yz  Zz  Tz ]        [  2   6  10  14 ]     
[  0   0   0   1 ]        [  3   7  11  15 ]
```

In GLSL the columns are addressed like this:

```
vec4 c0 = eyeTrans[0].xyzw;
vec4 c1 = eyeTrans[1].xyzw;
vec4 c2 = eyeTrans[2].xyzw;
vec4 c3 = eyeTrans[3].xyzw;
```

And the memory image of a 4*4 matrix looks like this:

```
[ Xx, Xy, Xz, 0, Yx, Yy, Yz, 0, Zx, Zy, Zz, 0, Tx, Ty, Tz, 1 ]
```

See further:

- [GLSL 4×4 Matrix Fields](http://www.geeks3d.com/20141114/glsl-4x4-matrix-mat4-fields/)